# How to download image from url then use this download in the app directly using File()

Tags: firebase, flutter, http, dart, firebase-storage

After  I upload an image to firebase storage and generate an url and put it in firestore. I want to create edit function that let the user change the photo

so what I want to do is that display the old image + add new image

but the problem is how I can convert the URL image that to image file so this widget accepted

```
FormBuilderImagePicker(
      onChanged: (value) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _focusList.length; i++) {
          _focusList[i].unfocus();
        }
      },
      key: ValueKey("Pics"),
      imageQuality: 100,
      attribute: 'Pics',
      initialValue: widget.picS.map<Widget>(
        (e) {
          widget.i++;
          return Image(
            image: NetworkToFileImage(
              url: e.toString(),
              file: fileFromDocsDir("${widget.i}.jpg"),
              debug: true,
            ),
          );
        },
      ).toList(),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelStyle:
            Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
        labelText: 'Select Images',
        helperText:
            'First Image will be the Preview Image',
        hintText:
            "if you add a picture here that mean you remove all the picture you add before",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).errorColor),
      ),
      onSaved: (value) {
        _pic = value;
      },
      validators: [
        FormBuilderValidators.required(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

the error: **type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'File'** so what I want is how to put in **initialValue** a list of file that contain the url image i get it from firestore as file in the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MAHMOODEBRAHIM Hi there,
You can use FutureBuilder or StreamBuilder to show SomeLoadingWidget and change ui. state to another view after downloaded it.

```
Future<String> _createFileFromString() async {
final encodedStr = await http.get("url_image");// in base 64 format f.e
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(encodedStr);
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
File file = File(
    "$dir/" + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() + ".png");//.png image format(it can be also jpg) 
await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
return file.path;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Image.file(your file)`. Note that you have to save the image to the device and give the path to it.

[Check out](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.file.html)

Comment: Thanks for your fast response but my problem here is how I can save the image and get the path before the screen created + the initial value of FormBuilderImagePicker accept File not image.file()